# How to find the difference between two matrices in Python with the result should not have any values with minus sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a Panda Dataframe with two columns (Word and Word_Position) in it. I need to find the distance between words and present the output in matrix form for better readability.

**What I have done so far is I have created a row matrix from the DF.Word_Position column and transposed it to create a column matrix. When I subtracted both these matrices, I am getting few values with minus sign before them.**

With all due respect to the great mathematics, this is absolutely correct but for my requirement I just need the number and not the minus sign.

Is there any other better way to do the same ? Appreciating your help. Thanks in advance.

***Note : I am using Python 3.6***

**Code snippets and its corresponding output for your reference**

```
m1 = np.matrix(df1['Word Position'])
print(m1)
[[ 1  2  3 ..., 19 20 21]]

m2 = np.matrix(m1.T)
print(m2)
[[ 1]
 [ 2]
 [ 3]
 ..., 
 [19]
 [20]
 [21]]

print(m2-m1)
[[  0  -1  -2 ..., -18 -19 -20]
 [  1   0  -1 ..., -17 -18 -19]
 [  2   1   0 ..., -16 -17 -18]
 ..., 
 [ 18  17  16 ...,   0  -1  -2]
 [ 19  18  17 ...,   1   0  -1]
 [ 20  19  18 ...,   2   1   0]]
```

Comment: May i know the reason why this question is downvoted ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take the absolute value?

```
np.abs(m2 - m1)
```

Your code indicates that your data consists of numpy arrays, so the solution above should work.

If they are dataframes, you could do:

```
m2.sub(m1).abs()
```

Comment: Thank You @Alexander. This looks pretty simple and much helpful to python newbies like me

Answer (score 1):

If you want the distance between to arrays, the proper way is to compute the [norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
dists = [np.linalg.norm(m - m2, axis=1) for m in m1[0]]
```

> This assume that shape of the arrays are `(n_sample, n_dimension)`.
>
> Instead of list comprehension, you can do numpy broadcasting on m2

---

I you want more control on the metric you might want to use [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist). This option is faster with large arrays. An example with the minkowski distance (p=2 for Euclidean distance):

```
dists = [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(m, m2, 'minkowski', p) for m in m1]
```

Of course, if the array is only 1D you can achieve that using an absolute value:

```
dists = np.abs(m1 - m2)
```

Comment: Thank you @Y0da. If I am not wrong, np.linalg.norm(m1-m2) or np.linalg.norm(m2-m1) will yield single value only. But what I need is an output in matrix form with values as distance between each and every word with one another

Comment: @JKC try to use the axis option: axis=1 or axis=0

Comment: Sorry @Y0da even with axis option I am not getting the desired output. May be this is not applicable to my requirement I feel. And Alexander's response is pretty much useful and simple.

Comment: @JKC what is the error? If you have two arrays with correct shapes (see above). Have you tried cdist?

Comment: there is no error. But it is not giving the output as i expected. Please see below for the output generated by your answer. np.linalg.norm(m2-m1, axis=1)
Out[384]: 
array([ 53.57238094,  49.70915409,  45.97825573, ...,  45.97825573,
        49.70915409,  53.57238094])

Comment: @JKC oh I see. You have to either broadcast m1 or you can use a list comprehension: dists = [np.linalg.norm(m - m2, axis=1) for m in m1]

Comment: @JKC There is an optional `keepdims=True` this can maybe solve this. I don't have a python interpreter right now to test it.

Comment: Thanks @Y0da but still I am getting same output even if I incorporate two of your recent options as well.

Comment: @JKC hum sorry I will check that and come back to you when working. I will update my answer accordingly:) From what I see something like: dists = np.linalg.norm(m1, m2[:, None], axis=1)

Comment: @JKC list comprehension is fixed. It was due to your shapping.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you probably want to use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist
m = df1['Word Position'].data[:, None]
dist = squareform(pdist(m, 'minkowksi', 1))
```

A bit overkill for this, but extensible if you ever want to change your distance parameter, and usually faster than broadcasting (since it only does half the subtraction steps as `abs(a-b) == abs(b-a)`).  If you want to do broadcasting you could always do this:

```
dist = np.abs(m - m.T)
```

Comment: I think your answer needs a 2D array as input. But my requirement involves two 1D arrays.

Comment: Yes. abs option is working as suggested earlier by other respondents